# Safari 14 (macOS). It's impossible to select a .webp file for uploading

Tags: macos, validation, input, safari

There is the input file for image uploading, accepting a list of image formats:

```
<input accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png, image/webp, image/bmp" type="file">
```

When I try to upload .webp file in Safari 14 (macOS), the file isn't selectable ([screenshot](https://take.ms/UIbYH), [.webp file](https://cross.expert/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/pryzhki-na-tumbu.jpg)).

Why does it happen?
Should I specify something else for Safari to accept .webp files?

**Note.**
If I remove the `accept` attribute, .webp files become selectable.

Comment: What is your version of safari? It may not support webp.

Comment: Safari 14.1.1. It supports webp, as far as I know. Moreover, I've tried to upload this webp file to the Google search for images, and it's been selectable (but that Google input hasn't had the `accept` attribute for its `input` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it works with the file extension adding to the `accept` attribute:

```
<input accept=".webp" type="file">
```